# NameValueCollection for editing query strings

Tags: asp.net

If I call

```
var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("?foo=bar&baz=robots")
```

I get back a NameValueCollection where if I call ToString on it, I get back a query string.

```
var str = nvc.ToString(); //foo=bar&baz=robots....
```

If I create a new NameValueCollection, add stuff to it, and call ToString() on it, I don't get back a query string.

```
var nvc= new NameValueCollection();
nvc["foo"] = "bar";
var str = nvc.ToString(); //default for Object.ToString()
```

Also there doesn't seem to be a way to construct a NameValueCollection that acts as a query string editor. Is there one? If not, why? Being able to edit query strings is a pretty useful thing, but this functionality is totally hidden away in an obscure mode of some object most people don't even know exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by the internal `HttpValueCollection` class, which inherits `NameValueCollection` and overrides `ToString()`.
`ParseQueryString()` is the only public way to construct this class.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, query strings are meant to be very simple. So, you can just do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("somekey", "someval");
var querystring = string.Join("&", dict.Select(kv => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kv.Key) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kv.Value)));
```

Completely untested of course. But yeah, a query string is name=value separated by ampersands. Is there something else you need to do?

Comment: no, I'm just annoyed that I have to replicate code that already exists in the framework