# String.Join return × instead of times?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

This is my code:

```
var signature_parameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "client_id", client_id },
    { "timestamp", timestamp },
};

var signature_base_string = string.Join("&", signature_parameters.Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.Key, p.Value)));
Response.Write(signature_base_string);
```

which prints `client_id=2446782×tamp=1291723521`

What is ×?

Comment: use HttpUtility class

Comment: Please *don't* build urls with `string.Concat` if possible... There are plenty of classes that deal whit Url creation correctly like [ParseQueryString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238190/namevaluecollection-for-editing-query-strings/7238228#7238228) or maybe `Url.Action` (for MVC)... And maybe see if you can avoid manual creation of HTML with `.Write` ....

Comment: I don't use .Concat. Can you show me a correct example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your join is putting the text `&times` into the string which is being encoded into `x` because `&times` is a [html named special character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm)

Comment: It's bit brute force, but I suppose you could use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @markzzz You can try to refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1877016/1180426), even though it's not standard-compliant and might fail if you have multibyte characters.

Comment: @owen79 Wouldn't `HtmlEncode`ing the string work just as well?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
var signature_base_string = string.Join("&amp;", signature_parameters.Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.Key, p.Value)));

Response.Write(signature_base_string);
```

Or you can use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert string to HTML- encoded string.

```
var signature_base_string = string.Join("&", signature_parameters.Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.Key, p.Value)));
Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(signature_base_string));
```